# Add view to a cell in a Table View Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with dynamic prototypes that is currently displaying 4 elements programmatically. I assign the cell names through an array (see code below), but I also want to add a small view to the right half of each cell in order to show a small graph next to each label. I can drop in a view in storyboard, but it doesn't extend itself dynamically. Basically I need to find a way to modify this code to add a view inside of each cell and assign a class I have already created to those views.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LineCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = oneLine.lineNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

This is where I want the views:

[image]

Also, how can I make more space between the Carrier, Time, and Battery and the table view?

Comment: You need to create a custom UITableViewCell class with your graph view and a label. 
Tons of tutorials online :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adP2dG_C1XU

Comment: Upvote for the drawing :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the view as you want and add it as subview of your cell's contentView:

```
var newView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 10, 100, 50))
cell.contentView.addSubview(newView)
```

Comment: Depending on the size of your device or the orientation (landscape or portrait) your code won't work everytime. That's why a solution using AutoLayout would be more complete.

Also it would prevent the label to be just hidden behind the supplementary view if it has a background, allowing it to be cut with an ellipsis.

Comment: this will keep adding view over older, every time cell is loaded

Answer (score 3):

To add "Space" between your tableView and the status bar you can embedded  your tableviewcontroller in a uinavigationconttoller.

To add a view dynamically you can use the method addSubview on your cell and add constraints in your code with the auto layout

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.0**

```
var newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 210, y: 10, width: 110, height: 50))
cell.contentView.addSubview(newView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 210, y: 10, width: 110, height: 50))
cell.contentView.addSubview(newView)
```

As ashish says, as far i know this will add the subview at the top of the cell. what should i do if i want to add it to the bottom of the cell.